# double converted to large number when mapping to int column

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm using `AutoMapper` to map datatable rows into class objects. One of the datatable's column is of type double whose equivalent property in the class is of type int:

```
DataTable source = new DataTable();
source.Columns.Add("ProductId", typeof(double));
source.Columns.Add("Code", typeof(string));
source.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
source.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(string));
source.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(double));
```

`ProductId` is double from the datatable and int on the class:

```
public class Products
{
    public Int32 ProductId { get; set; }
    public String Code { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public float Price { get; set; }
}
```

I'm mapping them by these lines:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<IDataReader, IEnumerable<Products>>();
IEnumerable<Products> products = Mapper.DynamicMap<IDataReader, IEnumerable<Products>>(source.CreateDataReader());
```

When mapping is done, for example the following row:

```
DataRow row = source.NewRow();
row[0] = 1.0;
row[1] = "Code";
row[2] = "Name";
row[3] = "Description";
row[4] = 4.75;
source.Rows.Add(row);
```

the result would be:

```
Code: "Code"
Description: "Description"
Name: "Name"
Price: 4.75
ProductId: 5102336
```

I tried adding a value converter as follows but nothing changed.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<double, int>().ConvertUsing(Convert.ToInt32);
```

Is this an issue between AutoMapper and IDataReader for double to int conversion?

Comment: Hmm it works fine for me - I got `ProductId = 1` without having to add the converter

Comment: @Rhumborl hey thanks for trying. did you install AutoMapper from the package manager console? What version are you using? Thanks!

Comment: I have reproduced the issue with AutoMapper 3.3

Comment: yes just the latest - 3.3.0.0 in a .NET 4.5 project / .NET4 Client also

Comment: @Rhumborl thanks. I was working with .NET 4.5 originally then changed the project to 4.0 and got no more issues. Tried to go back to .NET 4.5 again and got no more issues. weird...

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos are you in .net 4.5? can you try 4.0 then back again to 4.5?

Comment: I am using .NET 4.5. Switching to .NET 4.0 solved the issue. Switching back to .NET 4.5 and ProductId = 1. Inexplicable!